# HttpServletRequest without Servlet Container

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jax-rs, grizzly

I'm using Jersey with Jetty (or Grizzly) and wiring up the server like so:

```
final ApplicationHandler handler = new ApplicationHandler(resourceConfig);
server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, handler);
server.start();
```

Using this method to start Jersey, I don't have access to HttpServletRequest as the factories are wired up in WebComponent.  I can, however, inject javax.ws.rs.core.Request or org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest, but I'm not sure how to get from there to HttpServletRequest.

The reason I need the servlet request and response objects is that I am using filter API's that depend on them.  Am I wiring up Grizzly/Jetty wrong or do I need some sort of adapter factory for javax.ws.rs.core.Requests?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. You can't inject a `HttpServletRequest` at the application start up, no one has made a request yet.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that I'm trying to inject an HttpServletRequest using the Context annotation in a configured resource.  The problem is that the PerScope factory is only registered through the WebComponent, which isn't touched using the method above.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Grizzly you may want to create a server via GrizzlyWebContainerFactory from [grizzly2-servlet](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.glassfish.jersey.containers%7Cjersey-container-grizzly2-servlet%7C2.6%7Cjar) module. This way you should be able to inject HttpServletRequest.